How to access ckeditor5 features DropdownButtonView, createDropdown, addListToDropdown,DropdownView,ButtonView etc while using ckeditor5 from CDN?
While using ckeditor5 as node-modules features can be imported for example:
import {addListToDropdown, createDropdown} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/dropdown/utils';

But how to access these features when we are using ckeditor5 from CDN. Following is a sample code suggestion from one place but that is not working:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CKEditor 5 Customization</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/35.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="editor">
        <p>This is the editor content.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor5/35.0.1/ckeditor.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor5/35.0.1/ckeditor5-basic-styles/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <!-- Add other necessary plugins CDN links here -->

    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'heading',
                        '|',
                        'bold',
                        'italic',
                        '|',
                        'link',
                        'bulletedList',
                        'numberedList',
                        'blockQuote',
                        'insertTable',
                        '|',
                        'undo',
                        'redo'
                    ]
                },
                language: 'en'
            })
            .then(editor => {
                console.log('Editor was initialized', editor);

                // Access necessary modules from the editor instance
                const dropdownButtonView = editor.ui.componentFactory.create('DropdownButtonView');
                const createDropdown = editor.ui.componentFactory.create('createDropdown');
                const addListToDropdown = editor.ui.componentFactory.create('addListToDropdown');

                console.log(dropdownButtonView, createDropdown, addListToDropdown);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Also saw one suggestion somewhere like:
const view = new editor.ui.button.ButtonView(locale);
const dropDownView= new editor.ui.dropdown.DropdownView(locale);

this also doesn't seem to work and throws error "editor.ui.dropdown" is undefined. Can anyone please suggest some thing?

Have you checked this guide?: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/getting-started/installation/quick-start.html

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/getting-started/installation/quick-start.html  is providing an example using CDN where imports works but to make that work cdn library should be providing modules as export. What if I am using a ckeditor build which is not providing module as export. e.g.

Use as below:
import {addListToDropdown, createDropdown, ...all other imports} from 'ckeditor5';

